# how can I load a part of .mat file in matlab

Tags: matlab, mat, matlab-load

I've a mat file with 24 variables inside and I would like to load only the 100 first value of the variables named Var1 and Var2 in the mat file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [utility](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12250) on the File Exchange looks like it may do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the `matfile` function ([should](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/09/15/r2011b-is-available/) be available from 2011b on). The [documentation](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/matfile.html) explains it pretty well.

```
obj = matfile('test.mat')
% save a variable
obj.foo = magic(30);
% load a variable
obj.foo(5:10,3:4)
```

Comment: I can't find the original release notes, but it [seems](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/09/15/r2011b-is-available/) that it is available from 2011b on. Sry, I don't know about a ready-made solution for older versions. Maybe have a look at the Mathworks' File Exchange code sharing platform.

Comment: I've 2011a version :(

Comment: What I've done to load the first 100 value of VAR1 : load (Filename);i = strmatch('Var1',data.signals.labels,'exact');
    tmp  = data.signals.values(:,i);
    var1 = tmp(1:100,:);

Comment: @user2724407 Your are still loading the entire MAT file when calling `load(Filename)`

Answer (score 0):

In previous versions this is unfortunately not possible, see [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/10/14/new-mat-file-functionality-in-r2011b/)

Best option would thus be to load in all variables and then create new variables containing only the first 100 values.